# I have a flask application that I would like to convert into an executable

Tags: flask, py2exe

I have a flask application that I would like to convert into an executable for deploying elsewhere. I have used py2exe for that. I am getting **jinja2:TemplateNotFound error**. I have copied the **static** and **templates** folders into the **dist** folder where the exe files reside. Pls let me know if I am missing something. My setup file is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe 
import os 
from glob import glob 
import sys 
from distutils.filelist import findall 
import matplotlib 
matplotlibdatadir = matplotlib.get_data_path()  
matplotli bdata = findall(matplotlibdatadir) 
matplotlibdata_files = []
for f in matplotlibdata:     
    dirname = os.path.join('matplotlibdata', f[len(matplotlibdatadir)+1:]) 

    matplotlibdata_files.append((os.path.split(dirname)[0], [f]))  
data_files=[('static', glob("D:\\pythonLearning\\static\\*.*")), ('templates', glob("D:\\pythonLearning\\templates\\login.html"))] 
data_files.extend(matplotlibdata_files) 
print data_files 
sys.path.append('C:\\Windows\\winsxs\\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57')  

setup(     console=['myfile.py'],     
      options={  'py2exe': {    'packages' : ['matplotlib', 'pytz','werkzeug','email','jinja2.ext'], 
     'includes': ['flask','jinja2']   }     },     
data_files=data_files )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because jinja expects your egg to be unzipped and available via the filepath. [See](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#setting-the-zip-safe-flag)  for more information.

You can workaround this for typical data files using [this](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#accessing-data-files-at-runtime)
but jinja2 has no direct support for this and you would have to implement this yourself

Comment: Thanks.. I used the following line of code and things worked well..    `sys.path.append('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\jinja2')`